# Flutter. BLoC. Как обратиться к экземпляру класса блока внутри BlocProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui, dart-ui

У меня есть виджет-страница. Метод build возвращает BlocProvider. Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую я хочу отправлять event в поток.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как обратиться к моему bloc. Я пробую так: `BlocProvider.of<TimerBloc>(context)`
На что получаю ошибку:

> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a TimerBloc

Два вопроса:

1. Я правильно понимаю, что ошибка возникает, потому, что я пытаюсь найти свой BLoC, взбираясь по дереву виджетов, хотя это не требуется?
2. Как сделать правильно?

P.S. Только с этой надписью код адекватно форматируется.

```
class TimerPage extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<dynamic> showSetTimerAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => SetTimerWidget()
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TimerBloc>(
      create: (context) => TimerBloc(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Timer'),),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<TimerBloc>(context).add(TimerConfigurable());
                      showSetTimerAlert(context);
                      },
                    child: Text('Set timer',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: Size(300, 40),
                    )
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что выше контекста, по которому у вас идет запрос `TimerBloc`, нет `BlocProvider` с `TimerBloc`.

Если посмотрите внимательно, вы берете `context`, который пришел вам в `build()`, следовательно вы берете `context` у виджета `TimerPage`, который уже внутри себя содержит `BlocProvider`, то есть ниже по дереву.

Решения:

1. Поднимите `BlocProvider` выше `TimerPage` и тогда получится взять `TimerBloc` по этому же контексту.
2. Получите контекст виджета ниже `BlocProvider`, например, обернув `body: Container()` в `Builder` виджет, который подает `context`, у которого уже получится взять `TimerBloc` (так как этот `context` будет уже ниже `BlocProvider`).